# it's possible to generate documents in a different folder than the default folder directly from the Seettings or similar?

Tags: robotframework

I have one questions related with documents generated by RobotFramework

Do you know if it's possible to generate:

- Report.html
- Log.html
- Debug.log

in a different folder than the default folder directly from the "***Settings***" or similar?  (i know that this can be done using --outputdir)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its just about have some order in my folders, i would like to keep all the reports in a different folder than the scripts

Comment: Alright, you could do that with `--outputdir`, so I guess there is something else you need.

Comment: Hi @BenceKaulics yes, i would like to setup this into the script so the executer (another tester maybe...) don't have to be worry about nothing else than run the test

Comment: You can create one single argument file that contains all extra settings that could be set from command line only, so others would have to use something like this `robot -A path/to/all_settings.txt test.robot`.

Comment: That sound great @BenceKaulics. Thanks a lot i don't know that this was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer it's solved with this:

robot --outputdir FolderPath file.robot

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change those from within a .robot file.